# Does Winsock limit the number of concurrent connections?

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, client

I've recently made a program in C# (stress tester), which creates an array of 100,000 sockets, and connects each of them to a specified server.

Every time I have tested this, the program stopped at 16,334 sockets. The last connected socket was socket 16,334. They all stayed connected until I closed them, but still I couldn't connect more than 16,334 sockets to the same server.

Why does it happen? Is it a limitation of Winsock?

If so, can it somehow be bypassed?

Comment: I'm sure there are internal limits somewhere. And 16,334 is is "suspiciously close" to 16,383 (2^14-1) ..

Comment: @Tinwor "It must be emphasized that defining FD_SETSIZE as a particular value *has no effect on the actual number of sockets provided by a Windows Sockets service provider*. This value only affects the FD_XXX macros used by the select and WSAPoll functions." - all such resources I've seen related to such documentation have values like "64" or "128" which are a far cry from "16,334" (provider limit?).

Comment: @Tinwor, you are wrong. It says that the number of possible sockets depends on the amount of memory on the local computer, but when I connected all my 16,334 sockets to the server, the CPU and Memory didn't even come close to 100% (so it's not a problem of memory for sure). Also, the question is about number of connections and not number of sockets. I was limited by 16,334 connections, but I created 100,000 sockets with no problem at all.

Comment: As user2864740 hinted at, you are probably running out of available [ephemeral ports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port) for your connections. You could perhaps open more connections by opening a connection while specifiying explicitely a port number from the range of registered ports, but you will need to pay attention to not be hindered by network equipment or interference with other services wanting to use those ports. Also, i am not sure whether the server could handle that...

Comment: @elgonzo OK, Thank you, but isn't the port range 0 to 65,535? If so, shouldn't I be able to open 65,536 connections, instead of just 16,334?

Comment: No, because many of those ports are already in use, and because only a subrange of them is available for use as ephemeral ports. NB Winsock is an API. The implementation of TCP is in the operating system kernel. Any limitations will be imposed by the kernel.

Comment: @BlueRay010, for client-side ports, a Sockets implementation usually uses only ephemeral port numbers for connections where you do not explicitely specify the port for the client-side socket (see the Wikipedia article i linked in my previous comment for variations amongst different OS's). The vast majority of the possible 64K port numbers are so called well-known and registered port numbers (that means they are associated with a specific purpose/function) and will not be automatically used by the sockets implementation of your OS except for that specific purpose they are associated with.

Comment: @BlueRay010 from your just deleted question: take a look to encoders (properties in System.Text.Encoding, for example UTF8). They have a GetBytes() method to convert a string to bytes (respecting given encoding).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are limits on the number of outbound connections that you can make and knowing exactly what you mean by "stopped at" would likely help determine your problem. Which API is returning which error code causing you to "stop"?

The limits tend to be related to availability of ephemeral ports (see [MaxUserPort](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc938196.aspx)) and available memory and/or non-paged pool (though the later is rarely an issue on Vista or later).

You might trying running netstat when your process "stops" as this will show how many other processes also have connections established and are using ephemeral ports.

You could also take a look [here](http://smallvoid.com/article/winnt-tcpip-max-limit.html), as depending on the OS that you're running on some of the information may be of use to you.